# Haskell Cannot find gtk2hsChs

Tags: haskell, build, gtk2hs

Has anyone run into problems with gtk2hsChs installing glib with GHC on linux  (OpenSuse) and know of a workaround?

Here is the scenario: I have cabal installed gtk2hs-buildtools, and gtk2hsChs is in the path (e.g. which gtk2hsC2hs works).

However, I cannot install this library.  The program builds fine, but fails to install. If I

```
cabal unpack glib
cd glib
cabal configure
cabal build
```

Everything works just fine.  But

```
cabal install 
and
cabal install --global
```

fail.

```
Cannot find gtk2hsC2hs
Please install `gtk2hs-buildtools` first and check that the install directory is in     
your PATH (e.g. HOME/.cabal/bin).
```

Cabal-install doesn't have an option (as per --help) to change the location of gtk2hsC2hs, but

```
runhaskell Setup configure
```

does.  However,

```
runhaskell Setup configure --with-gtk2hsC2hs=/usr/local/bin/gtk2hsC2hs
runhaskell Setup build
sudo runhaskell Setup install
```

fails on the last step with the same error message as with cabal install.

The weird thing is this: If I change the location of the gtk2hsC2hs program manually in Gtk2HsSetup.hs, and run

```
cabal configure
or
runhaskell Setup configure
```

I get a different error message: setup: "Unknown build tool gtk2hsC2hs"  I can't find this string in any of the setup files, so it is being generated elsewhere.  Perhaps this indicates the problem.. perhaps a version mismatch.. perhaps something else silly I am missing?

Comment: Is it possible that you have changed your path, but are not exporting the changed version to subprocesses?

Comment: Also worth a look: what does `cabal install -v3` say? After you successfully `cabal build`, can you `cabal copy` and `cabal register` to complete the installation?

Comment: @DanielWagner: I have neveer changed my path manually.  I just installed gtk2hsC2hs to /usr/local/bin, so that bash always finds it.  For example, gtk2hsC2hs called on the command line, always succeeds.  Yes, cabal copy and cabal register work.

Comment: I also tested it by loading Glib.System.GDateTime, and obtaining the time, and everything seems to work.  So, now I'm just more confused.

Comment: It's even weirder.  I previously said that cabal copy and cabal register work.  However, if I configure with cabal configure --global, it fails with the original warning.

Comment: I haven't really got a clue. Do try with `-v3`, though.